# Convergent Sequence and its limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Can anybody help me out in this problem: 
[image: I am not able to figure out how the value of lambda in the 2nd problem comes out to be 2? In the first problem value of lambda came out to be 2 after squaring and solving the equation. (I am assuming that I am not making any serious/silly mistake here. )]

I am not able to figure out how the value of lambda in the 2nd problem comes out to be 2 ? In the first problem value of lambda came out to be 2 after squaring and solving the equation. (I am assuming that I am not making any serious/silly mistake here.

Comment: question 2. $\lambda =4$

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a mistake/typo on the part of the authors of the textbook, since solving the equation $\lambda = \frac\lambda 2 + 2$ clearly gives $\lambda = 4$.

I am thinking the textbook perhaps meant $x_{n+1} = \frac12 (x_n + 2)$, where then each successive $x_n$ is the average of the previous $x_n$ and $2$, so the limit at infinity would be $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: but the equation is $\lambda=\sqrt{2+\lambda}$ and not $\lambda=\frac{\lambda}{2}+2$

Comment: The OP said that "I am not able to figure out how the value of lambda in the _2nd_ problem comes out to be 2".

Comment: Ah my bad, read the wrong one then.

Comment: That's okay. :)